# Extract mkv metadata / headers into a file

Tags: metadata, extract, matroska, list

I've got several thousand mkv-files. I need to extract 2 metadata information of these files into a list, specifically the file resolution (e.g. 1920x1080) and if exists (!) the information the aspect ratio tag (e.g. 16/9 or 4/3).

If your are interested why I'd like to do this: I need to find all anamorphic files of my collection.

Would be great if you could help. :-)

Comment: Hi Basti303, I'm trying to work with WebM/audio files at the moment and am trying to do some automated processing with them, including accessing metadata. I'm currently at the stage of 'playing' with mkvtoolnix https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html. Are you familiar with this? Previously I was working from this webm parser in javascript, https://gist.github.com/mganeko/9ceee931ac5dde298e81#file-parse_webm-js , but it looks challenging at the moment!. Hope any of this this helps!

Comment: For windows: Downloadand install mkvtoolmix from here: https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix.html (a prompt to allow you to DL the GUI.exe is provided at the end of the toolkit install process, if you want it). You can then access the commands in powershell by opeing powershell in the installation directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix). type the following command: PS C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix> ./mkvinfo.exe 'path_to_your_file.ext'. I'm exploring other commands now...

Comment: Thanks, I'm playing a bit with mkvinfo later this evening. Let's keep us updated if we explore more help. :-)

Comment: via the GUI I found the necessary information 

via 
Tracks -> Track -> Video Track -> Pixel width, Pixel height, Display width, height, Display unit. Now I need to find a way to export these 5 informations via command line to some text file.

Comment: You'll be able to get that info in a terminal by moving/copying the ``mkvinfo.exe`` to the same folder as your files. Open PS in that folder and run: ``.\mkvinfo.exe 'path_to_your_file'``.  So far can only see how to to do it one file at a time.

Comment: Are you comfortable using node.js? If so, I have worked out how to run the terminal command from node using javascript, returning the result. You'll be able to loop over all your files then, and process the results. I have not researched / do not know how to do this for any other scripting language, i'm afraid.

Comment: Okay, to print the full information I have to use the "-o" flag. To loop it on Windows on all my files, I can use a batch file with the command "for %%a in (*.mkv) do mkvinfo.exe "%%a" -o". Now I have to find out how to extract the printed information into a file.

Comment: Nice. I cannot help directly with writing batch files, but this may answer your question - looks like you can make a log to hold you output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757525/printing-batch-file-results-to-a-text-file/7757781 Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo), and it's `--Inform` option to list only the information you need.

For example:

```
mediainfo --Output="Video;%Width% x %Height% DAR=%DisplayAspectRatio%" "$Your_Video_File"
```

If you are on a Mac or Linux (or using WSL in Windows), this will find all .mkv files in your current directory, and print the information for every file:

```bsh
find -iname "*.mkv" | while read f; do
  printf "%4s x %4s %6s    %s\n" $(mediainfo --Output="Video;%Width% %Height% %DisplayAspectRatio%" "$f") "$f"
done
```

Example output:

> ```
>  702 x  576  1.333    ./Alice in Wonderland.mkv
> 1920 x  800  2.400    ./The.Incredibles.2004/The.Incredibles.2004-stfr.mkv
> 1440 x 1080  1.333    ./Fantasia/Fantasia.1940-en_fr_it-de-st_en_it_de.mkv
> 1920 x 1080  1.778    ./Fantasia.2000/Fantasia 2000.1999.mkv
>  636 x  480  1.325    ./les maitres du temps-t7nTMeqwlmE.mkv
> ```